# This question is about the + or - sign

Tags: notation, arithmetic

Let's say i have (+/-)(3/2). This equals (+/-)(3)/(+/-)(2).
Does this equal +3/+2 = 3/2, and +3/-2 = -3/2 , or -3/2 and -3/-2= 3/2

The total number of answers equaling 2 : = 3/2 or -3/2?

Answer (score 1):

$±\frac{3}{2} = \frac{±3}{±2}$ as there are only two values which are +$\frac{3}{2}, -\frac{3}{2}$, but your reasoning is incorrect because $-\frac{3}{2} \ne \frac{-3}{-2}$.

Comment: I think you had it right before you edited this answer. please do go back to your old answer.

Comment: Well technically $±\frac{3}{2} = \frac{±3}{±2}$ because there are four possibilities which lead to the two signs (+ or -), so this answer is correct. The previous version said they weren't equal which is false.

Comment: I think that $\pm\frac{3}{2}$ unambiguously stands for $+\frac{3}{2}$ or $-\frac{3}{2}$. However, $\frac{\pm3}{\pm2}$ seems ambiguous to me, because I might think it means $\frac{+3}{+2}$ or $\frac{-3}{-2}$, which of course both equal $\frac{3}{2}$. When multiple $\pm$ are used in the same expression, such as $\sin(a\pm b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)\pm\cos(a)\sin(b)$, I assume they are "coordinated".

Comment: no i think that it was right before because 3/2 must be treated as one number and not two numbers. if you take the decimal it becomes 1.5 and the sign is still + or -.

Comment: Well in any case, I can't change my answer back, because when making edits a short time after posting the answer, the version doesn't show up.

Comment: if you had square root of 3 / square root of 2 however, i don't know if it would be treated as one number (square root (3/2)) or 2 numbers (square root 3)/(squareroot2)

Comment: and ok. i was having trouble with square roots in fact.

Comment: Square roots are positive by convention: $\sqrt{9} = +3$ only. We can choose either the positive or negative value to make the square root a function, where one input yields one output. Next time, please tell us your real question so that we can better help you.

Comment: would you mind explaining : ''Square roots are positive by convention: 9–√=+3 only. We can choose either the positive or negative value to make the square root a function''. i thought that square roots always had a negative/positive output. and what do you mean by making it a function?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{-3}{-2}$ is same as $\frac{+3}{+2}$

$\frac{+3}{-2}$ is same as $\frac{-3}{+2}$

So, you don't have $4$ cases, but $2$ distinct cases.